# Upgrade from Juno beta to final?

Tags: updates, release-juno

I've been using Juno Beta 2 and loving it. I just found that Juno final has been released. Since i have my laptop all set, i'd like to upgrade to final without losing anything. Is it possible? Does it upgrade automatically with simple updates, or do i have to clean install?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ll have to do a clean install. I would recommend it regardless to be honest. Good luck! Juno seems quite fresh in colours and slim in responsiveness!

Comment: Thanks Vincenzo. I'll backup everything and try it out.